Amazon Athena: SQL Query for Column values with different character legnths
I have two tables an "Enrolled Table" and a "Customer Table".
I only want to show all records on the Customer Table where the enrolled_no on the Customer table matches the enrolled_no on the "Enrolled Table".
Select all the records from the Customer Table by matching the enrolled_no column from both tables.
Assumptions:
On the Customer Table, the enrolled_no column is either showing the last 7-characters or 8-character in length of the enrolled_no from the Enrolled Table
The issue I have is on the Customer Table, because the column enrolled_no shows the last 7-characters or last 8-characters in length, how do I write a query that matches the enrolled_no from the Customer table to the Enrolled Table.
Enrolled Table



customer_id
enrolled_no




cust1
123a233e0000001


cust2
323a262e0000002


cust3
854a222e0000003



Customer Table



customer_id
product
enrolled_no




cust1
product1
e0000001


cust2
product2
0000002


cust3
product3
0000003


cust4
product4
na



Desired output



customer_id
product
enrolled_no




cust1
product1
e0000001


cust2
product2
0000002


cust3
product3
0000003



I have tried the below, but wanted to check if there is a better way to write the query
with enrolled_table AS (  

SELECT  
customer_id,  
SUBSTR(enrolled_no,-8) AS enrolled8,  
SUBSTR(enrolled_no,-7) AS enrolled7,  
FROM enrolled  
)  
SELECT*  
FROM customer c  
WHERE (  
c.enrolled_no in ( select enrolled7 from enrolled )           
or  
c.enrolled_no in ( select enrolled8 from enrolled)    
)


but, enrolled_table is never used ...

@BarbarosÖzhan I had to edit the Where Clause, but it is in the Where Clause where I tried to reference the enrolled table

You have to SELECT from enrolled_table to use its columns.

How do you know if it's the last 7 or 8 characters?

@jarlh sorry if my question was not clear. One of my assumptions is: On the Customer Table, the enrolled_no column is either showing the last 7-characters or 8-character in length of the enrolled_no from the Enrolled Table

Try
SELECT c.customer_id,c.product, c.enrolled_no  
FROM customer c  
inner join enrolled e 
  on SUBSTR(e.enrolled_no,-8)=c.enrolled_no
   or SUBSTR(e.enrolled_no,-7)=c.enrolled_no

Or
SELECT c.customer_id,c.product, c.enrolled_no  
FROM customer c  
inner join enrolled e 
  on SUBSTR(e.enrolled_no,-length(c.enrolled_no))=c.enrolled_no

Or
SELECT c.customer_id,c.product, c.enrolled_no  
FROM customer c  
  where exists
     (select 1 from enrolled e 
      where  SUBSTR(e.enrolled_no,-length(c.enrolled_no))=c.enrolled_no
     )


You can use the LIKE operator
SELECT 
    c.customer_id,
    c.product,
    c.enrolled_no
FROM Customer c
JOIN Enrolled e 
ON e.enrolled_no LIKE '%' || c.enrolled_no;

Output

